# What does this operator mean?

Tags: notation

I came accross this clock:
[image]

It features only the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in that order to get all of the numbers. However I have absolutely no idea what the notation is for number 5. If anyone cannot see the image it is basically $12_3$.

Just to clarify the answer to $12_3$ should be 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one of the common notations for numeral systems in different bases. In this case it is the [ternary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system). See, $12_3=1\cdot3^1+2\cdot3^0=5$.